# How to handle spaces with preg_split in PHP

Tags: php

I'm getting a `ftp_rawlist` of files from FTP in PHP.

I take the rawlist and run this code:

```
foreach ($ftp_rawlist AS $ff) {

    $ff = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $ff, 9);

    $perms = $ff[0];
    $user  = $ff[2];
    $group = $ff[3];
    $size  = $ff[4];
    $month = $ff[5];
    $day   = $ff[6];
    $file  = $ff[8];
}
```

This works fine, but if a `$ff[8]` has a space at the beginning of the file name, my code doesn't parse it to `$file`.

E.g. " file.pdf" is parsed as "file.pdf"

I'm not sure how to modify my `preg_split` to capture spaces.

Comment: Did you try http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php#110803 ?

Comment: Their `preg_split` is the same as mine.

Comment: I meant the entire function, not regex alone.

Comment: I tried the function but it still doesn't capture the leading space.

Comment: Please provide an example of the initial `$ff` (used as an argument of `preg_split()` function.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Remove the `+` symbol from the regexp by doing:

`$ff = preg_split("/[\s]/", $ff, 9);`

Cheers.